# Are variables obtained by destructuring a tuple mutable?

Tags: rust, tuples, destructuring, mutable

Does destructuring a tuple make the variable mutable?

This is the code snippet that confuses me:

```rust
let tup = ("duck", 11, true);

let (_, data, ..) = tup;
println!("data: {}", data);

let (_, .., data) = tup; // I expected that this is not available
println!("data: {}", data);

data = "what"; // like this, but then this one why not?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let` actually defines a new variable. So in your code, two `data` variables exist, one created by the first `let`, and one created by the second `let`.

That said, the second `let data` **shadows** the name of the first one, making the first one exist in the background somewhere but being inaccessible because its name has been reused by the second one.

This is also the reason why you don't need to declare the first `data` as `mut` - you never mutate it. It still exists in the background, the new `data` variable just stole the name.

The last line fails because `data` now refers to the second `data` object, which is a boolean. And you cannot assign strings to booleans. Apart of that, it isn't declared `mut`, so even if you wrote `data = false;`, it would fail to compile.

You **can** replace the last line with `let data = "what";`, then it will compile. But then you have three `data` variables now, with the previous two being shadowed.

To demonstrate that it is actually shadowed, here is a little example. It temporarily shadows the variable inside of the nested scope; after the scope the previous variable is reachable again because the nested one got dropped:

```rust
fn main() {
    let tup = ("duck", 11, true);

    let (_, data, ..) = tup;
    println!("data: {}", data);

    {
        let (_, .., data) = tup;
        println!("data: {}", data);
    }

    println!("data: {}", data);
}
```

```
data: 11
data: true
data: 11
```